# How to pass content yielded in cy.wait() to the variable and reuse it in the next steps?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cy.intercept

I use cy.intercept() and cy.wait() to listen to the request and yield content from it.

```
let number;

describe("some test", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.clearCookies();
  });
  it("some test", () => {
    cy.someCommand();
    clientPage.someMethod();
    cy.intercept("**/request").as("idNumber");
    clientPage.someMethod1();
    cy.wait("@idNumber").then((res) => {
      number = res.response.body.numbers.id
    });
    cy.get(#someELement).type(number)
 });
});
```

It gives me "cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined"
When I try to log cy.log(number) under "number = res.response.body.numbers.id" it works. When I try to pass the variable out of this code block it is undefined.
How can I pass it into the further steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure the value of number is passed on to the `type`, you have to add a `then`, something like:

```js
let number

describe('some test', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.clearCookies()
  })
  it('some test', () => {
    cy.someCommand()
    clientPage.someMethod()
    cy.intercept('**/request').as('idNumber')
    clientPage.someMethod1()
    cy.wait('@idNumber')
      .then((res) => {
        number = res.response.body.numbers.id
      })
      .then(() => {
        cy.get('#someELement').type(number)
      })
  })
})
```

If you want to use the variable globally throughout the project, you can use the `Cypress.env()` method. [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#Syntax).

```js
describe('some test', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.clearCookies()
  })
  it('some test', () => {
    cy.someCommand()
    clientPage.someMethod()
    cy.intercept('**/request').as('idNumber')
    clientPage.someMethod1()
    cy.wait('@idNumber').then((res) => {
      cypress.env('number', res.response.body.numbers.id) //Sets Number
    })
    cy.get('#someELement').type(Cypress.env('number')) //Gets Number and types it
  })

  it('some different test', () => {
    cy.get('#someELement').type(Cypress.env('number')) //types the number
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But what if I would reuse <number> in the next steps not necessarily in the next then() or even what if I would reuse <number> in the different it()?

Comment: Thank you. Your solution seems excellent, but it looks like Cypress.env stores the "number" value from the previous test. So when I try to use this number in the current test the code is not valid.
I log number from 
```cy.wait('@idNumber').then((res) => {
      Cypress.env('number', res.response.body.numbers.id) //Sets Number```
and then I try to log the same number outside of the block, 2 lines later. The first number is correct, but the second log shows the old code (from the previous test). The question is if it's the Cypress issue or the architecture of my app.

Comment: E.g.
```wait
@number
log
407288
log
474212
```
and next text will log:
```wait
@number
log
304431
log
407288
```

Answer (score 2):

@alex-izbas answer is good if you need for immediate use.

In the option that you need to use it later in your test, you'll need to set it an `.alias()` and use it in junction with `function(){}` and `this` keyword.

```js
describe("some test", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.clearCookies();
  });
  // use function() {} to be able to use this keyword
  it("some test", function() {
    cy.someCommand();
    clientPage.someMethod();
    cy.intercept("**/request").as("idNumber");
    clientPage.someMethod1();

    // use .its() to get the id and store in alias
    cy.wait("@idNumber")
      .its('response.body.numbers.id')
    // add an assertion to check type with .should()
      .as('number')

    // some more actions

    // get alias using this keyword
    cy.get(#someELement).type(this.number)
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately using this solution I am getting 
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'number')" The test doesn't even start.

Comment: Ops I forgot to erase the `let number` section.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the asynchronous nature of cypress, and at the moment `number` is called, its value was not assigned yet.
Any further action can be chained by `wait` command without polluting your scope with context variables:

```
 cy.wait("@idNumber").then((res) => {
    cy.get(#someELement).type(res.response.body.numbers.id)
 });
```